# How to abstract mouse movement event streams for networked multiplayer?

Tags: camera, networking, multiplayer, mouse

I'm building a mouse driven 3rd person shooter with client-server network architecture.

My input system is event based. Keyboard input is captured by `keys.S.onUp()` `keys.S.onDown()` events. When these events are triggered I immediately pass them across the network to be replicated on the server and other clients.

Mouse input is captured by a `mouse.onmove()` event that receives data from screen coordinates x,y. This method is fired constantly as the mouse is moved producing a flood of data. This may be premature optimization, but I feel like its a bad idea to immediately pass this flood over the network.

I currently have an abstraction that wraps the `mouse.onmove()` event and creates essentially a `mouse.moveStart()` and `mouse.moveStop()`. This significantly reduces the flood of mouse input to send on the network.

Unfortunately, this abstraction produces a less responsive feel on the local client experience. I am setting a `lookVelocity`. When `mouse.moveStart()` is triggered the camera position and player rotation is updated per-frame by the `lookVelocity` value. This produces a stiff fixed rate movement. If you rapidly move the mouse the camera movement is not reflected.

Additionally, this is an isomorphic/universal code base. Meaning I am using the same code between client and server. Ideally, I would like to reuse the same mouse event abstraction between both client and server.

Comment: Can't you use the onMove() localy and send the moveStart() and moveEnd() via network? In most cases that should be enough for remote characters.

Comment: @PSquall that is a good idea I will try. I was hoping there was some industry practice for handling this that I was unaware of. Is that how its usually done?